# Batch horizontal pod autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, hpa, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

Looking at [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) (pretty new to this), usecase I'm dealing with is to apply the same HPA rules to all deployment (in a specific namespace).

so I'd ideally want to implement something like this :

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: generalHpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: [deploymentObject1, deploymentObject2, deploymentObject3,...]
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

I was hoping to handle this via label/selector, whereas all deployment objects are marked with a specific label (e.g. `enableHpa`) and somehow use selector/macthLabels inside `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` to apply it to all those objects.
But it looks like `name` is required, and need to be targeted to a specific deployment object.

Any suggestion on how to handle this case and avoid creating `hpa`s one by one for every single `deployment` by name?

Comment: I think having `hpa` packed with each deployment manifest is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of setting up a new `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` object:

1. Declarative approach described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#creating-the-autoscaler-declaratively):

> #### Creating the autoscaler declaratively
>
> Instead of using `kubectl autoscale` command to create a HorizontalPodAutoscaler imperatively we can use the following file to create it declaratively:
>
> [`application/hpa/php-apache.yaml`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/application/hpa/php-apache.yaml) [image]
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
> kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
> metadata:
>  name: php-apache
> spec:
>  scaleTargetRef:
>    apiVersion: apps/v1
>    kind: Deployment
>    name: php-apache
>  minReplicas: 1
>  maxReplicas: 10
>  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
> ```
>
> We will create the autoscaler by executing the following command:
>
> ```
> kubectl create -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/hpa/php-apache.yaml
> ```

2. Imperative approach i.e. by invoking [`kubectl autoscale` command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#autoscale):

   ```
    kubectl autoscale deployment nginx-deployment --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=5
   ```

The first approach doesn't leave much room for further interpretation. The syntax is strictly specified and you cannot do much about it. As you can see both `kind` and `name` of our **scaling target** should be specified and although your pseudo code may seem like an interesting proposal, it have no chances to work. According to the specification `name` field is a **map/dictionary** and a **list** simply cannot be used in this context.

When it comes to the **imperative approach**, actually you can automate it by using a fairly simple **bash one-liner** and make your life a bit easier. If you have... let's say 50 different deployments and you want to `autoscale` all of them, it can save you a lot of time.

For the sake of simplicity I've created only 3 different deployments:

```
$ kubectl get deployments
NAME                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-deployment-1   3/3     3            3           4m3s
nginx-deployment-2   3/3     3            3           3m58s
nginx-deployment-3   3/3     3            3           3m54s
```

In order not to create **hpa** one by one manually, I used the following one-liner bash script:

```
$ for i in $(kubectl get deployments -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}');do kubectl autoscale deployment $i --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=3; done
```

the result of which is:

```
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/nginx-deployment-1 autoscaled
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/nginx-deployment-2 autoscaled
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/nginx-deployment-3 autoscaled
```

Command:

```
kubectl get deployments -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'
```

returns only the names of your deployments, so they can be easily iterated through a `for` loop. Notice that we still have 1-to-1 relation here. To one `Deployment` corresponds exactly one `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` object. If you additionally need to deal with different `namespaces`, the script can be further expanded.

Going back to your specific requirement, the question arises as to the legitimacy of such a solution. Although it may seem quite tempting to manage all your `Deployments` by one single `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` object (less work in the very beginning), if you take a closer look at all potential downsides of such approach, you would probably change your mind quickly. First of all, such solution isn't very scalable. In fact it is not scalable at all. Just imagine that for some reason you want to change the `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` for a single `Deployment` object. Well... you have a problem. It is managed by one global autoscaler and you need to quickly redesign your environment and create a separate hpa. So 1-to-1 relation between `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` and `Deployment`/`ReplicationController`/`ReplicaSet` makes a perfect sense. What you usually need is more granular level of control rather than possibility to manage everything by one huge general object.